# Loading class with interface from another class loader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a class `Foo` which implements an `IDoMagic` interface.
The `Foo` class is loaded by the system classloader and the `IDoMagic` interface is defined in a third party component, which I think loads the interface in another class loader (Dynamic Classloader).

When I try to create a new instance of `Foo`, I'm getting a `NoClassDefFound` for `IDoMagic`. I assume that's because it is loaded by a different class loader.

I have tried to create a `BridgeClassLoader` (similar to the one used by Guice) and then load class `Foo` from the system class loader and all other classes from a different classloader which I think is the one used for `IDoMagic` but without any success.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Classloaders (CL) in Java work on a delegate strategy which means that the CL first will ask her parent, which also asks her parent, if she knows the defintion for class X. Only if neither the parent nor any of the ancestors or the current classloader knew the classdefinition for X then the current classloader will load the definition from the respective `X.class` file.

If a class `Foo` is loaded by the system classloader, any classes `Foo` is dependend on need also be loaded by either the system CL or by a parent of this CL. As `IDoMagic` is provided in an other JAR, you most likely need to add this JAR file to the classpath (`java -cp ...` or `java -jar ...`). Due to the delegation model, any CL which is a (grand-; and so forth)child of this CL will also gain access to the class definitions loaded by any of the parental CL.

If `IDoMagic` needs to be loaded by a custom CL, `Foo` must not be loaded by the system CL but with either the custom CL or a child of this CL in order for the delegation strategy to kick in and provide the definition for `IDoMagic` if `Foo` is loaded/instantiated.

There is a custom delegation CL model where shared classes are kept in a kind of common CL list/array which may be used by dependend CL. The dependend classes are not direct children of the common CLs but are children to a delegation CL which simply delegates calls to the common ones before asking the parent if neither of the children was able to execute the task. One solution here might be a structure like this:

```
bootstrap CL
- system CL
  - delegation CL
    - common CL
    - plugin CL
      - plugin 1 CL
      - plugin 2 CL
```

Here, the delegation CL needs to delegate an invocation of `loadClass(...)` and `findClass(...)` to its contained common CL (object composition) and only if it couldn't find a definition delegate the call to his parent. Similar to this [still experimental class](https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication/blob/master/PluginFramework/PluginCore/src/main/java/at/rovo/core/classloader/DelegationClassLoader.java)

This delegation loader enables to load `IDoMagic` with the common CL f.e. and the `Foo` class with one of the plugin loaders, which is not a direct child of the `common CL`. However, this requires that the `delegation CL` propagetes all calls to the common CL first before asking the parent. Also, this delegation loader brings some overhead to the table as it makes one of the adavandages of custom CL (the unloading of unused classes) more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If a class loader receives a class load request, it does not self-load

Instead, the request is delegated to the loader of the parent class. If the parent class loader still has its own parent class loader, it is further requested

The request will eventually reach the top-level starting class loader, and if the parent class loader can complete the class loading task, it will return successfully

If the parent loader is unable to complete the load task, the child loader will try to load it itself. This is the two-parent delegation model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).